# unable to compile some code using latest dev branch ts compiler

Tags: typescript

i am trying to compile the code below using the latest dev version of the ts compiler but am getting the following error:

**error TS2137: Class test.CacheService declares interface test.ICache but does not implement it:**

this works fine using the 0.9.1.1 compiler. does anyone know what the issue may be? thanks again

```
module test {
export interface ICache {
    //indexer: [name: string]: any;
    get<T>(key: string): T;
    set(key: string, value: any);
}

export class CacheService implements ICache {
    private _cache: any = {};

    get<T>(key: string): T {
        //if (!key) {
        //    var tmp: T;
        //    if ($.isArray(tmp))

        return <T>this._cache[key];
    }

    set(key: string, value: any) {
        this._cache[key] = value;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is just a compiler bug (bisected to commit 38ffe2b730585b49e4792d20468 which went in a few weeks ago). If `T` is used in the parameter list, the compiler accepts the code. I've logged a bug.